is this system linear? causal?
$$y(t) = \int_{t_0}^t u(\tau)\, d\tau + y(t_0)$$
I have trouble determining whether this system is causal or not and linear or not.
I think this system is causal because it integrates input signals from $t_0$ to $t$. What I'm not confident in my answer is whether it is okay to consider $t_0$ as past. It is okay to consider $t_0$ as past?
For linearity, I think $y(t_0)$ would not be multiplied by $c$ if I put input signal $cu(t)$ into this system since $y(t_0)$ is just a constant.Therefore, I think this system is nonlinear. Is there no error in this thinking?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let $t_0 \rightarrow -\infty$ and let $y(-\infty)=0$.  Then what do you have?
